# Svg text according to the language to be used

Tags: html, svg, canvas, localization, html5-canvas

How can I make the text I want to show differ according to the language used.

Example if the text is in:

```
Spanish I would like to use the text: Hola!

Italian I would like to use the text: Ciao!

English I would like to use the text: Hi!
```

If no language is passed, a default one, for example English.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg height="30" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="blue">Hi!</text>
</svg>
```

Example for language selection, the language could be on cookie or session.

Or it could be passed as a parameter to the file `name.svg?Lang=es`

Comment: how do you change lang?

Comment: Using cookies or sessions for example, or you could switch the language you want to name.svg?Lang=es

Comment: if use session (php ?) simple change Hi! with an variable no?

Comment: In this case it is an environment where reactjs / angular is used, there is no support for php.
I found this: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch element. Change your browser's language settings to prefer Italian or Spanish to see the text change.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 100 600 300">
  <switch font-size="18">
        <g systemLanguage="en">
          <text x="20" y="220" xml:lang="en-US">Why can't they just speak English ?</text>
          <text x="230" y="150" xml:lang="en">English (US)</text>
        </g>
        <g systemLanguage="es">
          <text x="20" y="220" xml:lang="es-ES" font-size="18">¿Por qué no pueden simplemente hablar en castellano ?</text>
          <text x="230" y="150" xml:lang="en">Spanish (ES)</text>
        </g>
        <g systemLanguage="it">
          <text x="20" y="220" xml:lang="it" font-size="18">Perchè non possono semplicemente parlare italiano ?</text>
          <text x="230" y="150" xml:lang="en">Italian</text>
        </g>
    </switch>
</svg>
```

Comment: I do not know if it is working, at the moment I have a different language from the one I check, I check English but at the moment the language used is Italian.

As a browser I am using google chrome.

Comment: I'd rather avoid using the browser language, but switch the language or use that of a cookie / session.

Comment: @paul OK but that's too broad. Is the problem creating a cookie? Reading a cookie? Writing the code to switch languages having read a cookie? You'd need to show us how far you've got.

Comment: What I thought I was doing, but I can't find any way, define an example dictionary within the svg, then pass the language for example or read it from a cookie, and then print the text.

So if we want to put it short: define a text for each language and read the language and then use the correct one.

Comment: I found this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?lang=es&title=File%3ASystemLanguage.svg

There is a select that allows you to select the language, then the selected language changes url and consequently also svg.
But I didn't understand how it all works.

Comment: Search the page for the text "Render this image in"

Comment: That's not SVG at all. They have a png for each language and display a different file depending on which menu you select. If you want to see the SVG you need to click on the png image.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Browsers you can use a Custom Element to dynamically generate the SVG

Use Roberts `systemLanguage` to enhance the SVG
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/systemLanguage

For React you have to add extra wrapper code around every Custom Element,
React only supports this W3C standard [for 71%](https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/),
all other Frameworks are 100% BFF with the W3C standard Custom Elements API

```js
customElements.define('svg-text', class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["bgfill", "width", "height", "stroke", "fill", "text",
      "x", "y", "fontsize", "rotate"
    ]; // update whenever these attributes change
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    let [bgfill = "pink", width = 200, height = 150, stroke = "none", fill = "green",
      text = "Hello", x = "50%", y = "50%", fontsize = "1em", rotate = "0"
    ] = this.constructor.observedAttributes.map(x => this.getAttribute(x) || undefined);

    this.innerHTML = `<svg width='${width}' height='${height}'` +
      `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>` +
      `<rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='${bgfill}'/>` +
      `<text dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='middle' font-size='${fontsize}'` +
      ` x='${x}' y='${y}' fill='${fill}' ` +
      ` stroke='${stroke}' transform='rotate(${rotate} ${width/2} ${height/2})'>${text}</text></svg>`
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (this.isConnected) this.connectedCallback();
  }
});
// example changing attribute
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("svg-text").setAttribute("text", "Ola!");
}, 21e2)
```

```html
<svg-text bgfill='lightblue' fill="blue" width="100" fontsize="3em" height="100">
</svg-text>

<svg-text fill="green" width="75" height="25" text="Hallo">
</svg-text>

<svg-text bgfill="gold" fill="red" width="50" text="Bonjour" rotate="90" fontsize="2em">
</svg-text>
```

Comment: How do you say if I use react I should define a component?

Comment: You are on your own there, I advice my clients to ditch React, it is the new Flash, outdated technology

Comment: To leave react for what?
I'm confused.